# Referencing outlets with Tab Bar Application vs. View Based Application

Tags: tabs, interface-builder, label, uilabel

Okay, so I can successfully link a UILabel in the Interface Builder to whats written in my code by dragging the blue reference line to "File's Owner" and selecting the label I referenced in my code only when using a **View Based Application**.

However, using the exact same code and the exact same process in a **Tab Based Application** (hence dragging the blue line in the interface builder to "File's Owner" in FirstView.xib) the only option that show up when connecting the UILabel to "File's Owner" is "View" rather than the other options, such as "titleLabel or albumLabel", that I wrote in my code.

Please tell me is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try control-dragging (dragging while holding ctrl key) to the actual variable definition in FirstView.h (or equivalent file).

My experience is migrating to Xcode 4 and storyboards is a much cleaner solution. Connecting outlets/view transitioning is much cleaner in storyboards instead of old interface builders.

Comment: I will try that. Unfortunately my Macbook Pro runs 10.6.8, so it does not support XCODE4.

Comment: Thanks for the response but that still does not work. Unfortunately my Macbook Pro runs 10.6.8, so it does not support XCODE4. Ahh this is frustrating, I don't understand why "File's Owner" does not show the variables in my .h file.